# Terraform GCP VPC peering

Tags: vpc, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to configure a VPC peering between my project network and another project using GCP, however I can't because I don't have permissions to list networks on the other project.

```
resource "google_compute_network" "my-network" {
  name                    = "foobar"
  auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
}

resource "google_compute_network_peering" "my-network" {
  name         = "peering1"
  network      = "${google_compute_network.my-network.self_link}"
  peer_network = "${data.google_compute_network.another-network.self_link}"
}

data "google_compute_network" "another-network" {
  name    = "another"
  project = "another-project"
}
```

The error:

```
Error 403: Required 'compute.networks.get' permission for 'projects/another-project/global/networks/another', forbidden
```

Since terraform doesn't have access to `another-project` I would like to know if there is any other way to do this with terraform.

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know the name of the peer network just add the location:

`peer_network = "projects/PEER_PROJECT/global/networks/PEER_NETWORK"`

Comment: This is also a very useful answer to the related question, "How do I peer with a network in another project that isn't managed by this Terraform configuration?"

Comment: I have the problem and also tried --> peer_network = "projects/PEER_PROJECT/global/networks/PEER_NETWORK". But I still get a permission error. Is there a documentation how to define a remote project with terraform and GCP?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the selflink like that:
peer_network = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/**Peer_Project_ID**/global/networks/**Peer_network_name**"
Change Peer_Project_ID and Peer_network_name with the right value